# Georeferencer - Transform is not solveable

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am attempting to georeference a plat map. As others have reported, after loading a .png or jpeg raster, the georeferencer reports that the transform is not solveable. I have created new mapfiles, and ensured that all CRSs and projections are consistent. I cannot find any duplicate points.
I had no issues digitizing another raster the last time I needed to. Here are the GCPs and some screencaps of the georeferencer and QGIS:

[image: GCPs]

[image: Raster being digitized]

[image: The same points as shown in QGIS]

Answer (score 2):

Unclear on what the problem ended up being, but simply restarting my machine solved the problem in this case. As was suggested in another "transform is unsolvable" post, the previous georeferencing session may have been causing the problems.